# How to share a Sphinx documentation theme between multiple github repositories?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I work on an open source project that consists of a python API along with numerous [extension](https://tket.quantinuum.com/api-docs/) modules which are installed as separate python packages. All of these extensions live in their own github repositories.

I am currently trying to improve the appearance of our documentation by using a different sphinx theme (https://sphinx-themes.org/) as well as some custom CSS I've added myself. I have now updated the core repo to use the new theme. Here are the [docs](https://tket.quantinuum.com/api-docs/extensions.html) for the core package.

The problem is that under our current setup I would have to make about 15 separate (but almost identical) pull requests to update the theme in all of the different repositories. Whats more any changes I do make in the future will have to be made to each individual repository. This is clearly way too laborious not an optimal way of working whatsoever.

One solution I thought about was to have the documentation theme in its own repository and have the different projects pull in the shared theme somehow. Although I'm now sure how best to execute this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Python package of your theme, making sure you include its parent theme as a dependency in your requirements. [sphinx-book-theme](https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-book-theme/blob/master/pyproject.toml#L26) does just that.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem [when developing Trading Strategy documentation](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/).

Eventually, we gave up finding a very good solution for this, [and settle to have all documentation to a single Git repository](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/docs). Any package is [a git submodule dependency in this repository](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/docs/tree/master/deps).

Then we have [a manual script](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/docs/blob/master/scripts/update-deps.sh) to update dependencies and make a new commit and docs build, and also the same as a Github hook in CI actions.